# Dealing with Maven snapshots - best practices

Tags: maven-2, maven, snapshot, repository

I'm no maven guru by a long shot but I would appreciate some help.

Here's the situation:

I work in a large, distributed development team using Maven 2. We have a Nexus repository but it only holds releases, not snapshots.

The problem is 2-fold:

1. Every morning I have to svn up other modules I do not work on, build them and then build my module. This is because my module has snapshot dependencies on these other modules. This takes time and really adds up as everyone needs to do this to stay current.
2. Say module A needs module B and is declared as a snapshot dependency. Module B is updated to a higher version number but the developer forgets to update module A pom. So module A is using an older snaphot and it may not be identified for a while, probably only when its time to do a release.

So how best to deal with these issues?

Comment: You're in fact asking two questions so it's going to be hard to select one answer. I recommend splitting the question in two.

Answer (score 6):

> I work in a large, distributed
>   development team using Maven 2. We
>   have a Nexus repository but it only
>   holds releases, not snapshots.

This is the problem. Create a Snapshot repository in your nexus. As long as there is a clean separation between release repos and snapshot repos, there's no reason not to deploy snapshots to the nexus (I usually do it through a Hudson Job, so there is always a current version in the repo whenever a Hudson Job succeeds.)

Comment: they say they don't want to put snapshots in the repository.

Comment: @FinalFive They are wrong. That's the whole point of having [a separate `<snapshotRepository>`](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Repository)

Comment: I concur (as a Maven Dev and Nexus Dev). Nexus and Maven enforce separation of Snapshots on purpose, so there's no reason not to have them in the repo.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to depend on a special (snapshot) version (point 2 of your question) you should consider using [version ranges](http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnref-book/reference/pom-relationships-sect-project-dependencies.html#pom-relationships-sect-version-ranges) in your dependecy declaration:

Sample from the [Maven Complete Reference Book](http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnref-book/reference/public-book.html):

*JUnit version greater than or equal to 3.8 but less than 4.0*

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>junit</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
  <version>[3.8,4.0)</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Be careful, I think the handling of SNAPSHOTs (consideration in the range) differs between maven 2 and maven 3.

If you do not want to deploy SNAPSHOTS to your NEXUS repository (which would be the best way) you have to build the SNAPSHOTS by yourself as you do it already. Maybe scripting or continuous build tools like [jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/) (easy to use - even on your local machine) help you.

Comment: *Be careful, I think the handling of SNAPSHOTs (consideration in the range) differs between maven 2 and maven 3.* do you have any resources to back up this claim? That would be highly interesting to my current client...

Comment: @Sean Patrick Floyd: I mentioned this because I heard something about it (without knowing details). I checked it now and believe that you can find the details here: http://docs.codehaus.org/display/MAVENUSER/SNAPSHOT+Resolution

Answer (score 0):

The maven-versions-plugin has a [display-dependency-updates](http://mojo.codehaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/display-dependency-updates-mojo.html) mojo which you can use for finding out if you're not using the latest version of an artifact.

Comment: While this is handy, it doesn't help in this situation (it only helps if there is a repository where these versions are deployed).